# Como cargar datos de una URL en ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Quiero cargar opciones un select usando ajax. La url de donde quiero cargar las opciones es de esta url: https://www.etnassoft.com/api/v1/get/?get_categories=all

Soy nuevo en ajax y estoy haciendo esto:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    //SELECT OPTION 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    https:www.etnassoft.com/api/v1/get/?get_categories=all,
    dataType: 'json',
    //data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        //$('#lCategorias').html(response);
        //console.log(response);
        //console.log(1);
        // for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        //     $("#sCompany").append(
        //         '<option value='response['idCompany']'>'response['Name']'</option>';
        //     )
        // }
    }
});
```

});

```
    <form class="container-fluid">
    <select id='lCategorias' name="lCategorias" class="search-select">
    <option id="resp"></option>
    <!--<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
    <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
    </select>-->
    </form>
    <br>
     <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

Me puedn aconsejar por favor y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las mil formas i mas sencillas seria de esta manera @SantySteinS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var api = 'https://www.etnassoft.com/api/v1/get/?get_categories=all';
  $.ajax({
        url: api,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data)
            $('#combo').children().remove();
      for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++){
              $('#combo').append('<option value="'+ data[a].category_id +'">' + data[a].name + '</option>');
      }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="combo"></select>
```

Comment: Gracias funciona, si quiero ejecutar el script en el controlador y llamarlo desde la vista, debo declaralo en funcion? y como lo llamaria desde la vista o debo ejecutarlo en la vista?